# Confusion Trying To Move Sinatra style Forms into Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

To learn rails, I'm trying to build an app, where a user has the ability to buy phone numbers via Twilio. Initially, I started out with 2 models to accomplish this; the user has_many phone numbers, and the phone_numbers belong to users. I think I have this part handled, but what I'm confused about is how to implement the ability to

(1) Search Phone Numbers
(2) Once that Number Is Selected, populate it into a form to push that, alongside other info to the database.

I'm looking at this doc to try to figure it out -- http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/search-and-buy

but, it's written in Sinatra, a light ruby framework, and the most experience I have is finishing Michael Hartl's book on Rails.  The meshing together of the controller and the views are really confusing me.

Looking at it, I thought that I would need to create a new controller, say find_numbers, which has a new, create, and show action. The create action would than render the phone_numbers controller's new action, which would than post it to the database.

But, here's the tricky thing. I don't know how to move fields of information, which aren't in a database, over to a different view.

For example, say I have this in the find_numbers view

```
  <form method="POST">
    <label>near US postal code (e.g. 94117): </label><input type="text" size="4" name="in_postal_code"/><br/>
    <label>near this other number (e.g. +4156562345): </label><input type="text" size="7" name="near_number"/><br/>
    <label>matching this pattern (e.g. 415***EPIC): </label><input type="text" size="7" name="contains"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH"/>
  </form>
```

Because these aren't database values, how would I tell the create action, to use these as parameters to list the numbers? Here's what they wrote in Sinatra, for the create action

```
post '/search-numbers' do
  account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  auth_token = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'

  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

  search_params = {}
  %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
    search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
  end

  begin
    local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
    numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)

    unless numbers.empty?
      out = '<html><head><title>Choose a number</title></head><body><h3>Choose a number</h3>'
      numbers.each do |number|
        out << "<form method='POST' action='/buy-number'>"
        out << "<label>#{number.friendly_name}</label>"
        out << "<input type='hidden' name='PhoneNumber' value='#{number.phone_number}' />"
        out << "<input type='submit' value='BUY' /></form>"
      end
      out << '</body></html>'
    else
      '<b>Sorry!</b> Twilio doesn\'t have any numbers available that match those constraints.'
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    '<b>Sorry!</b> ' + e.message + '.'
  end
end
```

Can someone help me deconstruct this code? As in, what would be in the create view, what would be in the create action? Is my new view even okay?

After that, I guess the way to tell the new action of the phone_number controller which phone number to by is by adding it to the url, like /phone_number=123123123, and that will populate the field, and I can make Twilio buy from there.  But...the top part is really confusing to me...

How would you implement this?

---

My attempt at it was like this --

for the create action

```
  def create
@user = current_user
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(current_user.twilio_account_sid, current_user.twilio_auth_token)
 search_params = {}
  %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
    search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
  end

local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
@numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)

  end
```

For the create view

```
          <%= numbers.each do |number| %>
       <form method='POST' action='/buy-number'>
       <label><%=number.friendly_name %></label>
       <input type='hidden' name='PhoneNumber' value='#{number.phone_number}' />
       <input type='submit' value='BUY' /></form>
      <% end %>
```

But I get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `numbers' for #<#<Class:0x597cc48>:0x5979570>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's gotten a lot more clear than this. My problem initially was that I didn't understand how rails handled forms, and if it could receive information on fields that weren't connected to the database.

http://www.guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html helped a lot, so here's how my controller looks like now :

```
class FindNumbersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = current_user
    end

    def create
        @user = current_user
        render 'find_numbers/show'
    end

    def show
        @user = current_user
        client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)

        search_params = {}
          %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
            search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
        end

        local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
        @numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)    


    end

end
```

I still have a problem with the show action, but it's outside of the scope of this question.